# Resizing imageview on screen touch

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, size

I've got an imageview that resizes to a random size within a given range. The method below is called in onCreate and works fine when it's called the first time. However when it is called in onTouchEvent, the method runs but doesn't resize the imageView.

```
public void setInnerCircleSize()
{

        widthMultiplier = r.nextInt(75 - 25) + 25;
        widthToSet = ((widthScreen / 100) * widthMultiplier);
        circle.getLayoutParams().height = widthToSet;
        circle.getLayoutParams().width = widthToSet;

}
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            if(hitCheck == true)
            {
                hitCheck = false;
                setInnerCircleSize();
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
            hitCheck = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

setInnerCircleSize is being called fine when there is a motionevent and the random variables are created so there's nothing wrong in that respect. It's just that it won't resize a second time even though it worked perfectly fine when called from onCreate.

Comment: You should know that android MotionEvents are best effort delivery. You are not guaranteed to get a `ACTION_UP` for every `ACTION_DOWN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invalidate the view to tell android to redraw it. Since you are changing the view bounds, I think you are suppose to use:

```
View.requestLayout();
```